# Android - Adding tabs Dynamically

Tags: android, tabs

I have to add n number of tabs with the same layout (say llItemList which is declared in xml) in all the tabs.  In the below snippet when I create n number of tabs. All the layout uses the same copy of llItemList, instead of the tab's own copy. Could you please let me know how to create a individual copy of llItemList in all the tabs which will be created dynamically. 
Thanks in Advance

```
    //---------------------------------
    // insert the tabs dynamically
    //--------------------------------- 
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        final String tabName = "tab" + Integer.toString(i);
        final TabSpec ourSpec = th.newTabSpec(tabName);
        ourSpec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() { 
            public View createTabContent(String tag) { 
            ourSpec.setContent(R.id.llItemList);   
            TextView text = new TextView(NewTicket.this);
            String tabText = tabName;
            text.setText("You've created a new tab " + tabText); 
            return (text);
            }
        });
        ourSpec.setIndicator(tabName);
        th.addTab(ourSpec);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a `TabSpec` either by specifying

- the id of a View, **or**
- a `TabHost.TabContentFactory` that creates the View content

Your code does both!

Change your code to one of the following:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    final String tabName = "tab" + Integer.toString(i);
    final TabSpec ourSpec = th.newTabSpec(tabName);
    ourSpec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() { 
        public View createTabContent(String tag) { 
            TextView text = new TextView(NewTicket.this);
            String tabText = tabName;
            text.setText("You've created a new tab " + tabText); 
            return (text);
        }
    });
    ourSpec.setIndicator(tabName);
    th.addTab(ourSpec);
}
```

or

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    final String tabName = "tab" + Integer.toString(i);
    final TabSpec ourSpec = th.newTabSpec(tabName);
    ourSpec.setContent(R.id.llItemList);   
    ourSpec.setIndicator(tabName);
    th.addTab(ourSpec);
}
```

**Edit:**

To preserve the same instance of `ListView`, as mentioned in your comment, do the following:

1. Register a `TabHost.OnTabChangeListener`
2. When the tab changes, you should first call `removeView()` on the ListView's current parent and then `addView()` it to the new parent.

Comment: I have used the 2nd option. Now I have a listview attached to the layout. This will be a common layout for all the dynamic tabs. Can you provide any sample for this scenario.

Comment: You mean all tabs should have the same **instance** of the ListView?

Comment: Thanks Deeraj.. you solved my problem.         if (currentTab.equals("item1")){
          adapter=new Adapter(this, item1);  
             list1.setAdapter(adapter);
         }   in this where i need to use removeview() and addview()

Comment: Though it is working. I still have aquestion in using removeview() and addView(). Will this affect any performance ?    Is there is any alternative to get an instance of a listview so that each tab will have its own copy of the listview, so that there will be noo need to use removeView() and addView().

Comment: Performance should not be a problem. Whether to have a new instance of ListView or not is up to the requirement of your application. It is unusual, though, to `addView()` and `removeView()`. You may have different instances of ListView and still provide the illusion of the same instance by selecting the list item of the previous instance and scrolling to the same position.